# Discord.py change_nickname error too many arguments

Tags: python, discord

I am currently trying to make a command with discord.py to reset all user nicknames on a server (!!!mreset). However I'm getting a type error which tells me 4 arguments were given.

Code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
     return

  if message.content.startswith('!!!mreset'):
     serverid = message.server.id
     x = message.server.members
     for member in x:
       await client.change_nickname(serverid, member.name, None)
```

Error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Saber\PycharmProjects\my_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Saber/PycharmProjects/my_bot/my_bot.py", line 32, in on_message
    await client.change_nickname(serverid, member.name, None)
TypeError: change_nickname() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Comment: If look at the [source code](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/client.py#L1936) `change_nickname` takes only 3 parameter `self, member` and `nickname`. But in your case `client.change_nickname(serverid, member.name, None)` will pass four paramter to the function. ie, `self(client object), serverid, member.name` and `None`.(which will result in `TypeError: change_nickname() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`)

Comment: @a_python_user please post this as answer

Comment: @NitinSingh not necessarily. It looks like *a_python_user* is just trying to clarify where the OP is going wrong. At times, comments are helpful enough for the question to be solved. In case it doesn't solve the problem/ confusion, then writing an answer would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the `serverid`, or a `Server` object to `change_nickname`.  `Member` objects have a server associated with them, so the command can get the appropriate `Server` from the `Member` object.  You should also be passing a `Member` object and not the `Member.name` attribute.

```
if message.content.startswith('!!!mreset'):
    for member in message.server.members:
        await client.change_nickname(member, None)
```